# Change "library view" to show album names instead of artist and track pane doesn't show tracks?

Tags: cmus

In `cmus` is there a way I can show the album's name instead of the artist?

Currently my library looks partially like this:
[image: library]
also, based off that image, shouldn't the "Track" part on the right show the tracks in that album?

I can view the tracks in the sorted view:
[image: tracks]

Answer (score 8):

Cmus isn't entirely intuitive about this.  Use the win-toggle key (space) to show an artist's albums and the win-next key (tab) to move focus to the track list.

See the following [tutorial](http://www.tuxarena.com/static/cmus_guide.php) for more information:

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but cmus 2.6.0 now show all tracks when artist is selected in the tree view.

https://github.com/cmus/cmus/releases/tag/v2.6.0

[image]